# Google App Engine Node.js App - “Error parsing app.yaml: Unknown url handler type”

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, yaml

I recently set up a Node.js app in Google App Engine and it is running fine. I tried to add handlers so that all the requests to website can be redirected to https URLs. Below is my `app.yaml` file

```
# [START runtime]
runtime: nodejs
vm: true
# [END runtime]

# Temporary setting to keep gcloud from uploading node_modules
skip_files:
- ^node_modules$

# [START handlers]
handlers:
- url: /.*
  secure: always
# [END handlers]
```

When I tried to run the upload script, `gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml`, it throws below exception:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) An error occurred while parsing file: [/Users/rakesharidasan/BackwaterBreaks-UI-Release/app.yaml]
Unknown url handler type in  line 14, column 17 (end of # [END handlers]).
```

I could see similar questions in StackOverflow, but many of them were related to indentation or white space issues. I believe my app.yaml got right indentation and I checked it through few online parsers eg - http://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator

The upload script will still run if I remove the handlers part from yaml.

Any ideas what goes wrong here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The handler section must also specify a handler type, in this case a script or the main entry point to your app

Example:

```
- url: /.*
  script: app.js
  secure: always
```

Comment: Perfect!!! That solved the issue. It should have been really nice if the app engine upload  script gives a better error message. Thank you very much for your help @jeffrey-godwyll

Comment: Note for Node 10 (now the default): rather than provide the JS source, you say 'auto'. Otherwise gcloud will say: "INVALID_ARGUMENT: script field for handler '/.*' must be set to 'auto' for runtime nodejs10."